# How can I check for isObject in AngularJS template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am displaying fields in an AngularJS template like this

```
{{ field }} :   {{ data[field] }}
```

I want that if `data[field]` is an object then display `Object` word as string like, instead of displaying the whole object as a JSON :

```
{{ isObject(data[field]) ? {{ data[field] }} : 'Object' }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use angular.isObject to check typeof as in javascript, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isObject

```
  angular.isObject(title) ? 'Object' :'not an object'
```

or you can also check

```
  angular.equals({},object)
```

For your above scenario you can use it as filter like as shown below

```
 {{text | isObject}}

  App.filter('isObject',function(){
        return function(input){
            return angular.isObject(input) ? 'its a OBject' : 'not an object'
        }
   })
```

//can be verified in controller

```
    <p>{{AmIObject(text)}}</p>

     $scope.AmIObject = function(input) {

      return angular.isObject(input) ? 'its a OBject' : 'not an object'
  }
```

Comment: can i use that in template

Comment: @user3214546  good approach is that you can use filter for this or you can aslo add that in your controller scope and can be checked  it whether its an object or not ,

Answer (score 0):

If it's an object or array of object, you can do something like

```
<span ng-show="data[0][field]"></span>
```

This should give an idea to display whether it's an object or not.

Answer (score 0):

in .js

```
$scope.isObj = angular.isObject;
```

in .html

```
<span ng-bind="isObj(data[0][field]) ? data[0][field] : 'not an object'"></span>
```